# SMB session setup failed: NT_STATUS_LOGON_FAILURE

Tags: active-directory, window, smb, impacket

I'm setting a mini Windows AD.

My setup is a Windows Domain (2019), a W10 Client and a Linux Machine

When I am accessing the C$ of the W10 client with smbclient as any user (even Administrator from AD), I have the following error:

`session setup failed: NT_STATUS_LOGON_FAILURE`

What should be the problem? (Note, all the settings are default)

Also, the following error from the impacket tools:

`impacket.dcerpc.v5.rpcrt.DCERPCException: rpc_s_access_denied`